# How to vertically justify elements in a container without flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `ul` element of height 270px. There are 10 `li` elements inside it. I want all the `li` elements to be vertically **justified** -- i.e. the top and bottom `li` elements must touch the top and bottom of the container respectively and the remaining elements should adjust their spacing. I have no issues with display type of any element. 'li' elements can be inline, inline-block or block level. Following is the code:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul {
  height: 270px;
  width: 250px;
  color: #afafaf;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
li {
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>- Web/UI Design</li>
  <li>- Web Development</li>
  <li>- CMS Integerations(WP, Joomla)</li>
  <li>- Logo & Banner Design</li>
  <li>- PSD to XHTML, CSS 3.0, HTML5</li>
  <li>- PHP & MySQL</li>
  <li>- jQuery, Ajax, Flash(ActionScript)</li>
  <li>- Landing Page Design & SEO</li>
  <li>- SEO(Search Engine Optimization)</li>
  <li>- E-Commerce & Shopping Cart</li>

</ul>
```

Not ot mention that I have gone throught various posts explaining how to vertically **align** elements. I want them to be **justified**. I know it can be done with `display: flexbox`, but I want to target older browsers too which do not support `flexbox`.

Comment: Have a look at this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/wr5U4XO5RgiUxmflHx3i?p=preview)

Comment: @SatejS If I decrease the number of `li` elements then they do not get justified vertically.

Comment: That is correct.I am assuming that you have 10 elements and thus the 10% height for each element.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to do what you're asking:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul {
  height: 270px;
  width: 250px;
  color: #afafaf;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  display: table;
}
li {
  width: 240px;
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>- Web/UI Design</li>
  <li>- Web Development</li>
  <li>- CMS Integerations(WP, Joomla)</li>
  <li>- Logo & Banner Design</li>
  <li>- PSD to XHTML, CSS 3.0, HTML5</li>
  <li>- PHP & MySQL</li>
  <li>- jQuery, Ajax, Flash(ActionScript)</li>
  <li>- Landing Page Design & SEO</li>
  <li>- SEO(Search Engine Optimization)</li>
  <li>- E-Commerce & Shopping Cart</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: There is a small issue remaining. The last element must touch the bottom of the container. Do I do something like vertical-align: bottom with the last element?

Comment: Hmmm, it's not ideal but you could do `li:last-child { height: 10px; }`

Answer (score 0):

Just add "line-height: 1.7;" to your li. It will be done.
As you can see below

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul {
  height: 270px;
  width: 250px;
  color: #afafaf;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
li {
  width: 240px;
    line-height: 1.7;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>- Web/UI Design</li>
  <li>- Web Development</li>
  <li>- CMS Integerations(WP, Joomla)</li>
  <li>- Logo & Banner Design</li>
  <li>- PSD to XHTML, CSS 3.0, HTML5</li>
  <li>- PHP & MySQL</li>
  <li>- jQuery, Ajax, Flash(ActionScript)</li>
  <li>- Landing Page Design & SEO</li>
  <li>- SEO(Search Engine Optimization)</li>
  <li>- E-Commerce & Shopping Cart</li>

</ul>
```